# Page not scrolling down even though when reached bottom in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have certain items mapped with initial size of 5, when reached to the bottom expected to load more 5 items and increase accordingly with pages more than 40. Its like infinite scrolling. But, here the scrolling stops with only 15 elements and page 3. Following is the code for reference

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(PAGE_NUMBER);

const scrollToEnd = () => {
  setPage(page + 1);
};

console.log("Page", page);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=${page}&size=5`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => setState([...state, ...json.data]));
}, [page]);

window.onscroll = function () {
  if (
    window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight
  ) {
    scrollToEnd();
  }
};

return (
  <>
    {state.length > 0 &&
      state.map((el, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="container">
          <h4>{el.id}</h4>
          <h4>{el.name}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
  </>
);
```

Any appropriate solution is highly appreciated

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sn31v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a useEffect and in that useEffect you can add a event listener for scroll and check if user scrolled enough.

Working clone project: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rr9th

```
useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const windowRelativeBottom = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      // user scrolled enough
      if (windowRelativeBottom <= document.documentElement.clientHeight + 100) {
        setPage(pageCount => pageCount + 1);
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

### Resources

- https://javascript.info/onscroll